# Android studio error:Error:(23, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments on root project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I reinstalled android studio, I am using the same project with android studio in another PC so the code is probably fine!
It is the full error:

```
 Error:(23, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_1z9k6ruj47plglocgqknjnoag$_run_closure3@133cf914] on root project 'allthingsvegan-android-9d296805dc64' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Open File

---

**The solutions I've found on the internet was including changing the code.. So they are not relevant to me**

Thanks!!
build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Try to clean Project

Comment: show your build.gradle

Comment: I've edited the original post with the build.gradle

Comment: trying to clean the project didn't success (same problem as mentioned here)

Comment: @ligi forgot to notify you

Answer (score 2):

It is the top-level `build.gradle` file.
In this file you can't use this block:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
}
```

Remove this block.

Answer (score 1):

you need to apply the android plugin:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

this needs to be done after buildscript like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Im really new in android studio.
what does build script mean?
where do i need to write it?
@ligi

Comment: Thanks
I've changed it, now the error is:
compile sdk version is not specified
@ligi

Comment: do you have 2 build.gradle files in your project?

Comment: yea, I think so, one under gradle folder and one under gradle scripts @ligi

Comment: change to the following: https://gist.github.com/ligi/a141bc2219d3bfef2cbf0bf91f589a70

Comment: Im not sure, in android studio its seems like I do have duplicate gradle files.
but in file explorer its seems to be only one...
@ligi

Comment: I've replaced all the txt in there to txt u gave me.
Now there is this error:
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.1
I want to thank you again - you are very helpful :)
@ligi

Comment: i cannot :/
But it's really weird that the problem is the code because the exact same code worked on my PC

Comment: the problem is not in the code but in your build-scripts - and I do not think they work on a PC and not somewhere else ..

Answer (score 0):

- uncomment android tag present in **build.gradle(Project:android-start)**
  [image]
- rebuild the gradle it asks to update .
- Update the gradle then sync it works